# Why valgrind "valid value" need 8 bits?

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

Visit http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.machine

valgrind using V bits to verify the validity of data. In my opinion, only 1 bit can verify the validity, but why valgrind need 8bits?

Comment: I would assume that this is so it can check the validity even of bitfields. If you set a bitfield to all ones, other bits that may reside in the same word or byte as the bitfield may remain invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocations are in units of bytes. That is, the integer you pass to `malloc` is the number of bytes you want to allocate. So memcheck only needs one bit per byte to track whether a memory address has been allocated.

But initialization can work on individual bits, not just on whole bytes. If all bits of byte X are uninitialized, and then I execute `X = X | (1 << 3)`, then just one bit of X is now initialized. So memcheck tracks whether each individual bit has been initialized. Since there are 8 bits in a byte (on all CPUs that memcheck supports), that means memcheck needs another 8 bits per byte to track which bits have been initialized.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it's explained right here:

> It is simplest to think of Memcheck implementing a synthetic CPU which is identical to a real CPU, except for one crucial detail. Every bit (literally) of data processed, stored and handled by the real CPU has, in the synthetic CPU, an associated "valid-value" bit, which says whether or not the accompanying bit has a legitimate value. In the discussions which follow, this bit is referred to as the V (valid-value) bit.

So every single bit in the Valgrind testing environment has a corresponding valid-not valid bit to track its validity. This can be especially important for bit-fields, where a single bit can represent something like a Boolean value, represented only by one bit.

At this level, Valgrind is going for absolute precision on memory resolution down to the binary level, it seems, in order to provide for a good datascape on which it can observe and perform analysis.